# Webpage is referenced in the wrong location

Tags: php, html, netbeans-8

I'm following the beginner tutorial "Creating a Database Driven Application With PHP" in net beans.

I created the wishlist.php file that is referenced in the index.php file.
When I run the index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="wishlist.php" method="GET" name="wishList">
      Show wish list of: <input type="text" name="user" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the form comes up. I enter 'tom' and select the 'go' button.

According to the tutorial an empty page with the following URL should appear:

```
 http://localhost:90/Lesson2/wishlist.php?user=tom
```

I get a webpage with the message:

> This webpage is not found

and upon selecting 'more':

> No webpage was found for the web address:
>    file:///C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/wishlist.php?user=tom Error
>    code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

I don't know where the path "C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/" came from.

Comment: *How* are you running the php script? - are you connecting to a local webserver, or just double clicking it in explorer?

Comment: I assume you have installed a server such as apache. Look for a folder called htdocs that is the place where you need to put your files

Comment: I'm running it from net beans ide editor.

Comment: apache is installed and running. All files are under htdocs

Comment: When you set up the NetBens project, what was the project config.? Specifically "Run Configuration".

Comment: The config was 'default' run as 'script'

Comment: @ALL: I suspect that net beans found the path "C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/" in the registry and modified it or perhaps assigned it to it's own variable. But I can't find any reference to it,

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is nothing wrong the posted part of your script. As you can see your form redirects to the page it should redirect to. PHP is not even executed so we are assuming this will work when it is triggered correctly ;-)

But as I can see in your error description you are running the script locally in your home folder of your PC. Is there an webserver running? For executing PHP scripts you basically need to run a PHP service - usually a webserver like apache2.

If you don't have one try [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) which will install an apache webserver on your local PC.

Comment: I used xampp to install it all.

Comment: I am not familiar with the configuration of xampp or NetBeans but maybe you should try to point your browser to http://localhost/ . In some browsers it is important to enter also the protocol (http). Then you should look where the htdocs folder resides like @jtorrescr suggested. Put your file there and execute it. If you make any changes to the file reload them with CTRL+R.

Comment: He has both: http://localhost:90/Lesson2/wishlist.php?user=tom but I'm not sure why he uses port 90 instead of 80? Maybe that's something specific on the NetBeans environment.

Comment: @Daniel:" http://localhost:90/Lesson2/wishlist.php?user=tom" is what the tutorial suggests should show on the webpage. I've not specified localhost:90 anywhere as far as I can remember

Comment: @PeterStewart and what about if you just open http://localhost/ ? What  do you see, an error page or an list of files ?

Comment: localhost opens localhost/xampp/ and displays the Welcome to xampp for windows page

Comment: Usually /path/to/xampp/htdocs is the root directory of XAMPP. Try placing your codes there instead of file:///C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/ - "localhost" routes to the XMAPP root - not to your custom folder.

Comment: All my files are under xampp/htdocs. C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/   hasn't been entered by me anywhere. I first looked there when it showed up on the error message:   "No webpage was found for the web address:
file:///C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/wishlist.php?user=tom Error
code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: So basically the message that it doesn't exist is correct because there really is no wishlist.php under file:///C:/Users/Peter/AppData/Local/Temp/ ??? And localhost:90/Lesson2/ should redirect to xampp/htdocs/Lesson2/ where the correct wishlist.php is?

Comment: @Daniel: That is it in a nutshell!